# Toggle data based on checkbox value with morris.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, lines, morris.js

I'm getting trouble in making what I want `morris.js` charts to do.

My goal is to be able to toggle specific lines based on `input[type=checkbox]` value.

So far here's what I have done:

**JS code**

```
var morris = Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#activate').on('change', function() {
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      console.log(isChecked);
      if(!isChecked) {
        morris = Morris.Line({
          element: 'line-example',
          ykeys: ['a']
        });
      }
    });
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<body>
  <div id="line-example"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="activate" checked="checked"/> Activate
</body>
```

---

The problem is that the chart duplicates itself with both lines showing up.

Any idea where to investigate to? (I'm not asking for someone to make up the code for me, I just need some tips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might be interested in the solution (works for toggling one line):

**JS code**

```
<script>
function data(toggle) {
  var ret = [
      { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
      { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
      { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
      { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
      { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
      { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
      { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
    ];


  if(toggle == 1) {

    for(var i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
      delete ret[i].b;

  }

  return ret;
};

var morris = Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: data(),
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#activate').on('change', function() {
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if(isChecked)
      {
         morris.setData(data(0));
      } else {
         morris.setData(data(1));
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ztbu8oo/

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code a little bit, and I got a 3rd line in there that responds to being checked, but there's a bug that brings back the third line when the second one is unchecked.

```
/*
 * Play with this code and it'll update in the panel opposite.
 *
 * Why not try some of the options above?
 */
function data(toggle) {
  var ret = [
      { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90, c:80},
      { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65, c:80 },
      { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40, c:80 },
      { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65, c:80 },
      { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40, c:80 },
      { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65, c:80 },
      { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90, c:80 }
    ];


  if(toggle == 1) {

    for(var i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
      delete ret[i].b;
  }
  if(toggle == 2) {

    for(var i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
      delete ret[i].c;

  }

  return ret;
};

var morris = Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: data(),
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B', 'Series C']
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#activate').on('change', function() {
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if(isChecked)
      {
         morris.setData(data(0));
      } else {
         morris.setData(data(1));
      }
    });
});
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#activate1').on('change', function() {
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      if(isChecked)
      {
         morris.setData(data(0));
      } else {
         morris.setData(data(2));
      }
    });
});
```

Here's your fiddle edited a bit. And thank you for having this question!!

Comment: This is not a bug. This is normal behaviour as such the variable `ret` is redefined each time you call `setData` so it doesn't remember the previous checkbox being checked. This is why I've specified that my answer worked for toggling one line. If someone is willing to upgrade my solution, this'd be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wrapper for morrisjs which allow you to toggle data.

https://github.com/vadimmanaev/morrisjs-toggle